# How to pass or share mutex in class member in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, mutex

I want to develop a logger class. So I decided put all related code to the read operation in the
**dataLogger** class.
In the **dataLogger** with a thread, I want to able write data in a buffer, which named “queue_”. In main class that contains an object of **dataLogger**, I want to able read from the “queue_” with another thread. Therefore, I use shared_pointer to access the buffer.
Is it possible to use one mutex to manage read and write operation?
Actually, I want to pass the mutex witch created in main class to the dataLogger class.
I used QtGuiApplication to illustrate my problem.

**In main.cpp**

```
#include "QtGuiApplication8.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtGuiApplication8 w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**In QtGuiApplication8.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_QtGuiApplication8.h"
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include "dataLogger.h"

using namespace std;

class QtGuiApplication8 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtGuiApplication8(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplication8Class ui;

    std::thread thread_;
    bool thread_flag = false;
    void thread_fn();
    std::mutex mutex_;

    shared_ptr < vector<std::shared_ptr<vector<uint8_t>>>>  queue_;
    dataLogger dataLogger_;
};
```

**In QtGuiApplication8.cpp**

```
#include "QtGuiApplication8.h"

QtGuiApplication8::QtGuiApplication8(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    queue_ = make_shared< vector<std::shared_ptr<vector<uint8_t>>>>();
    dataLogger_.setQueue(queue_);
    // setMutex(mutex_); //I want same thing like this line !   
    dataLogger_.run();

    thread_flag = true;
    thread_ = std::thread(&QtGuiApplication8::thread_fn, this);

}

void QtGuiApplication8::thread_fn()
{   
    while (thread_flag)
    {       
        while (queue_->size() != 0)
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> f(mutex_);
            //  auto scan_raw = queue_->back();         // at this line I want to read queue_
            }
        }
        Sleep(20);
    }
}
```

**dataLogger.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <thread>
#include <mutex> 
#include <vector>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
using namespace std;

class dataLogger
{
public: 
    void setQueue(shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<vector<uint8_t>>>>   q) { queue_ = q; };
    //void setMutex(mutex* m) {  mutex_ = *m; };   //I want same thing like this line !
    void run();
    void stop();

private:
    std::thread thread_;
    bool thread_flag = false;
    void thread_fn();
    std::mutex mutex_;
    shared_ptr<vector<std::shared_ptr<vector<uint8_t>>>> queue_;
};
```

**dataLogger.cpp**

```
#include "dataLogger.h"

void dataLogger::run()
{
    thread_flag = true;
    thread_ = std::thread(&dataLogger::thread_fn, this);
}

void dataLogger::stop()
{
    thread_flag = false;
    if (thread_.joinable())
        thread_.join();
}

void dataLogger::thread_fn()
{
    std::shared_ptr<vector<uint8_t>>    rawData_;
    rawData_ = std::make_shared<vector<uint8_t>>(10);
    vector<uint8_t> sasaa;

    while (thread_flag)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> f(mutex_);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                rawData_->at(i) = i;    // simulation data source

            queue_->push_back(rawData_);
        }
        rawData_ = std::make_shared<vector<uint8_t>>(10);
        Sleep(20);  
    }
}
```

Comment: _I want to pass the mutex witch created in main class to the dataLogger class._ Why?  Doesn't `DataLogger` own the mutex?  Anyway, `std::mutex` is neither copyable nor moveable so you are going to have a hard time doing this.

Comment: thanks. Why? To simplify the use of this code in other projects.

Comment: OK, well you could pass it in by reference, but that would be very fragile as you would have to make sure that the mutex doesn't go out of scope while the `dataLogger` is using it.  How about turning things around?  If you need access to the mutex outside the class, provide an access routine that returns a reference to it.